# Spread objects into a state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to spread values as objects into a state array in react, but this code causes this error:

Error:

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
> In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a `[Symbol.iterator]()` method.

Is there a chance I can spread values from the `data` array into a `values` state array as objects, so `values` array would be the same as the `data` array?

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const q = query(collection(firestore, 'places'));

            await getDocs(q)
                .then((data) => {
                    data.forEach((item) => {
                        if (item.exists()) {
                            setPlaces((prevState) => [...prevState, ...item.data()]);
                        }
                    });
                });

            setIsLoaded(true);
        };

        getData();
    }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The reason for that is to think of `data` as an await array that comes from the server

Comment: never call `setState` directly in the rendering pass. Why not `const [values, setValues] = useState(data);`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli the question is mostly about the spread syntax which would preserve the previous value

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I utilize `useEffect` for fetching the data, and now need to somehow spread all objects into a state array as **objects**

Comment: @Aleksandrs - Your question isn't at all clear about that, not least because you've referenced an infinite loop, which won't occur if you have your `useEffect` coded correctly. Please update the question to accurately reflect your actual code.

Comment: Note that if `data` is coming from the server, there's no need to copy the objects in it; just use them directly: `setValues((prevValues) => [ ...prevValues, ...data ]);`

Comment: The code shown in your edit will not cause an infinite loop. (Separately: If you're using `await`, using `.then` isn't necessary and only adds confusion.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `setPlaces((prevState) => [...prevState, ...item]);` caused error: `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.`

Comment: @Aleksandrs - That's not an infinite loop. You've missed out your `useState` for `places`/`setPlaces`, but it sounds like you didn't initialize it with an array.

Comment: `const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);`

Comment: I think you need, `[...prevState, item.data()]``

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - While that might work, it's a bunch of unnecessary state updates. Better to do a single state update by mapping the items and then calling `setPlaces`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true. Was trying to understand what `item.data()` was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `item.data()` doesn't return an iterable.

There's no need for that `forEach`, just use the data directly. If you need to map it (sounds like you do, calling `item.data()` on each `item`), you can use `map` for that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        const q = query(collection(firestore, "<collectionName>"));

        const data = await getDocs(q);
        setPlaces((prevPlaces) => [
            ...prevPlaces,
            ...data.map((item) => item.data()),
        ]);
        setIsLoaded(true);
    };

    getData();
}, []);
```

That spreads the new array from `map`, it doesn't try to spread `item.data()`.

---

In a comment you've said that using `data.map(/*...*/)` causes:

> `data.map` is not a function

That means `data` **isn't** an array as the question states, it's some other kind of collection with a `forEach` method.

If it's an *array-like*¹ or an iterable, you can do the mapping with `Array.from`:

```
setPlaces((prevPlaces) => [
    ...prevPlaces,
    ...Array.from(data, (item) => item.data()), // ***
]);
```

If it's not an array-like or iterable, then worst case, you can use `forEach` to create a new array:

```
const mapped = [];
data.forEach((item) => mapped.push(item.data()));
setPlaces((prevPlaces) => [
    ...prevPlaces,
    ...mapped
]);
```

---

¹ *"array-like"* - Has a `length` property and has properties for its elements with names that are the indexes `0` through `length - 1`.

Comment: Error: `data.map is not a function`

Comment: @Aleksandrs - Then data **isn't** an array as claimed in the question. It's something else with a `forEach`. Please try to provide complete **and accurate** information when posting questions.

Comment: @Aleksandrs - I've updated the answer to account for this latest change.